# Total number of event logs then piped out to a CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, get-eventlog

I've got the below

```
Get-EventLog -LogName * -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-7)
```

Which returns the information I require:

[image: Event log return]

Now when I export this information out with

```
Export-Csv c:\temp\$([Environment]::MachineName).csv
```

It returns the following under the entries section in my CSV:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryCollection
```

I will be running this on multiple servers and collecting all logs into one area.

So Now I have changed the information to be a bit more specific

```
Get-EventLog -LogName * -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-7) |
  Select-Object MachineName, Log, Entries |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\$([Environment]::MachineName).csv
```

This now returns the below when I'm exporting out to a CSV:

[image: New Export]

But I can't see the amount of entries I require. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Entries` property contains a collection. You need the `Count` of that collection. You may also want to replace the `MachineName` value (`.` for the local computer) with the actual computer name. [Calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) are the usual way to achieve this:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName * -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-7) |
  Select-Object @{n='MachineName';e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Log,
                @{n='Entries';e={$_.Entries.Count}} |
  Export-Csv "C:\temp\$env:COMPUTERNAME.csv" -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-NoTypeInformation` switch parameter to omit the type header:

```
$data | Export-Csv C:\temp\$([Environment]::MachineName).csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It still returns the System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryCollection  on the entries column, is this because it's the first column within the CSV?